# Vue Dropdown onChange callback does not run when the device is an iPhone

Tags: vue.js, dropdown

This code works on desktop. I have not had other mobile devices to test on. On iPhone Safari, the dropdown disappears when an option is selected but the selected option is not changed. In landscape orientation, it sometimes works on iOS.

Here is the dropdown code (BaseSelect.vue)

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import HelperMethods from '@/methods/helper';
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
defineProps({
  label: {
    type: String
  },
  selectedOption: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String, // adjust this to whatever type `modelValue` should be
    default: '' // adjust this to whatever default value you want
  },
  choices: {
    type: Array<string>,
    default: () => []
  },
  autoCapitalize: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  disabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
})


const onChange = (value: string) => {
  console.log('changed');
  emit('update:modelValue', value)
}

</script>

<template>
  <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
  <VDropdown :class="{ error: error, disabled: disabled }">
    <button v-if="choices.length > 1" type="button">

      {{ autoCapitalize ? HelperMethods.uppercaseFirstLetter(selectedOption) : selectedOption }}
      <span>&#9660;</span>
    </button>
    <h3 v-else>
      {{ autoCapitalize ? HelperMethods.uppercaseFirstLetter(selectedOption) : selectedOption }}
    </h3>
    <template #popper>
      <div class="select-content" :v-bind="$attrs">
        <button v-close-popper @click="onChange(choice)" v-for="choice in choices" :value="choice" :key="choice"
          :selected="selectedOption === choice" type="button">
          {{ autoCapitalize ? HelperMethods.uppercaseFirstLetter(choice) : choice }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </template>
  </VDropdown>
</template>
<style scoped>
.select-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
</style>
```

Here is the page where I use the BaseSelect component:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/useAuthStore';
import { useWebsiteDataStore } from '@/stores/websiteDataStore';
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue';
const authStore = useAuthStore()
const websiteDataStore = useWebsiteDataStore()
const currentWebsiteUrl = ref('Loading...')
const name = ref("Website Customer");
websiteDataStore.init(authStore.user?.uid!).then(() => {
  currentWebsiteUrl.value = websiteDataStore.websites[websiteDataStore.currentWebsiteIndex].url
})

onMounted(async () => {
  const dbName = await authStore.getName()
  if (dbName) {
    name.value = dbName
  }
})

watch(currentWebsiteUrl, (newUrl) => {
  const websiteIndex = websiteDataStore.websites.findIndex((website) => {
    return website.url === newUrl
  })
  websiteDataStore.currentWebsiteIndex = websiteIndex
})

</script>

<template>
  <BaseSelect v-if="websiteDataStore.websites.length > 0" :choices="websiteDataStore.websites.map((website) => {
    return website.url
  })
    " :autoCapitalize="false" :label="`Now viewing:`" v-model="currentWebsiteUrl"
    :selectedOption="currentWebsiteUrl" />
  <nav-bar>
    <RouterLink :to="{ name: 'WebsiteStats' }">Stats</RouterLink>
    <RouterLink :to="{ name: 'content' }">Content</RouterLink>
    <RouterLink :to="{ name: 'forms' }">Forms</RouterLink>
    <RouterLink :to="{ name: 'settings' }">Settings</RouterLink>
  </nav-bar>

  <div>
    <RouterView v-if="websiteDataStore.websites.length > 0" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: by any chance does the element have the following ```CSS properties```: ```visibility: hidden```, ```opacity: 0```, or ```display: none``` ?

Comment: @cantdocpp Which element?

Comment: the button element ?

Comment: @cantdocpp I do not. The buttons show up, but the click event does not seem to run

Comment: are you using some kind of component library ?

Comment: @cantdocpp Yes, floating vue: https://floating-vue.starpad.dev